# PHP Beginner Column not found 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, crud

The goal is to code php files so I have the ability to perform CRUD functions on categories.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why I'm getting an this error . Check the image below!

But after changing it i get Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_category_id' in 'field list' on line 43?

Line 43

```
$q->execute(array($category_category_id,$category_name,$id));
```

[image]

updateCategory.php

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';

    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
    $category_nameError = null;
        $category_category_idError = null;

        // keep track post values
    $category_category_id = $_POST['id'];
    $category_name = $_POST['category_name'];


        // validate input
        $valid = true;


        if (empty($category_category_id)) {
            $category_idError = 'Please enter Category id';
            $valid = false;
        }
        if (empty($category_name)) {
            $category_nameError = 'Please enter Category name';
            $valid = false;
        }

        // update data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE category set category_category_id = ?, category_name = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($category_category_id,$category_name,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    } else {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM category where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $category_category_id = $data['id'];
        $category_name = $data['category_name'];

        Database::disconnect();
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Update a Category</h3>
                    </div>

                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="updateCategory.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
                        <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($$category_category_idError)?'error':'';?>">
                            <label class="control-label">Category Id</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                    <input name="id" type="text"  placeholder="Category Id" value="<?php echo !empty($category_category_id)?$category_category_id:'';?>">
                                    <?php if (!empty($$category_category_id)): ?>
                                        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $$category_category_id;?></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($category_nameError)?'error':'';?>">
                            <label class="control-label">Category Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                    <input name="category_name" type="text" placeholder="Category Name" value="<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
                                    <?php if (!empty($category_nameError)): ?>
                                        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $category_nameError;?></span>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                      <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Product Menu</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>CategoryId</th>
                          <th>Brand</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Barcode</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include_once 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['brand'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['barcode'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }

                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>

              <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <h3>Category Menu</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <p>
              <a href="createCategory.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
              </p>
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Category Id</th>
                <th>Category Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>


            <?php
            include_once 'database.php';
            $pdo = Database::disconnect();
             $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id ASC';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                 echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td width=250>';
                 echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                 echo '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';

             }
             Database::disconnect();
            ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
      <!--              <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                    </p>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>CategoryId</th>
                      <th>Catengory Name</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
                  foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row) {
                       echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';

                       echo '<td width=250>';
                       echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                       echo '</td>';
                       echo '</tr>';
                     </div>
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table> -->
```

Comment: check if you are getting a value in `$_POST['category_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You need to initialize the variable in the code like this 



require 'database.php';

$id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if ( null==$id ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$category_category_id = "";
$category_name = "";

if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track validation errors
$category_nameError = null;
    $category_category_idError = null;

    // keep track post values
$category_category_id = $_POST['id'];
$category_name = $_POST['category_name'];


    // validate input
    $valid = true;

    if (empty($category_name)) {
        $category_nameError = 'Please enter Category name';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($category_category_id)) {
        $category_idError = 'Please enter Category id';
        $valid = false;
    }

    // update data
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE category set id = ?, category_name = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($category_category_id,$category_name,$id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $category_category_id = $data['id'];
    $category_name = $data['category_name'];

    Database::disconnect();
}
```

also change the input field name

```
<input name = "category_name" id="catogortId" type = "text" placeholder = "Category Name" value = "<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```

Comment: But after changing it i get Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_category_id' in 'field list' on line 43? This is line 43 $q->execute(array($category_category_id,$category_name,$id));

Comment: Thanks It works now ! I'm going to read it and see what I did wrong

Answer (score 1):

You don't have put *name* attribute value in form so put it like :

```
<input name="category_name" type="text" placeholder="Category Name" name="category_name" value="<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have `category_name` field.

Change:

```
<input name="category_id" type="text" placeholder="Category Name" value="<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```

To

```
<input name="category_name" type="text" placeholder="Category Name" value="<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```

Comment: But after changing it i get Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_category_id' in 'field list' on line 43? This is line 43     $q->execute(array($category_category_id,$category_name,$id));

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `name = "category_id"` to `name = "category_name"` in updateCategory.php file

Change

```
<input name = "category_id" type = "text" placeholder = "Category Name" value = "<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```

TO

```
 <input name = "category_name" type = "text" placeholder = "Category Name" value = "<?php echo !empty($category_name)?$category_name:'';?>">
```